# How to delete only text files except few files

Tags: batch-file

In a certain path I have some different kinds of file type. Eg., .txt, .bas, .cls, etc.
I need to delete only the text files in that path except few files.
For eg, if the path has `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`, `aa.bas`, `bb.cls`, it should delete only `a.txt`. It should not delete `b.txt` and `c.txt` (Also it should not delete the other extension files).

Comment: Well, what about `del "a.txt"`??

Comment: I need to delete lot of files. Not just one. If the path is having 20 .txt files, I may need to delete around 12.

Comment: Your question is currently unclear. Please can you explain your criteria for deletion, unless we know that we cannot help you with a fully compliant solution.

Comment: Well, since your question is quite unclear, you should not expect clear answers. At first you need to clarify by what criteria files are to be selected for deletion; then you need to show your own efforts for solving it. Please take the [tour] and consult these help articles: [ask] and [mcve]!

Comment: see edited version below where I added a script which you can delete files not in the exclusion file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all `?.txt` files in the root folder, excluding `b.txt` and `c.txt`

```
@echo off
for %%i in (?.txt) do (
     if not "%%~nxi"=="c.txt" if not "%%~nxi"=="b.txt" echo del "%%i"
)
```

To do this in the root and subdirectories:

```
@echo off
for /R %%i in (?.txt) do (
     if not "%%~nxi"=="c.txt" if not "%%~nxi"=="b.txt" echo del "%%i"
)
```

If the files are to be all `*.txt` files and not just single digit as per your example (add `/R` to recurse:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
     if not "%%~nxi"=="c.txt" if not "%%~nxi"=="b.txt" echo del "%%i"
)
```

Similarly, but using findstr to only exclude:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d ^|findstr /vi "b.txt" ^|findstr /vi "c.txt"') do (
  echo del "%%i"
)
```

and to search only include:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d ^|findstr /i "a.txt"') do (
  echo del "%%i"
)
```

and to include and search subdirectories:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s /a-d ^|findstr /i "a.txt"') do (
  echo del "%%i"
)
```

On all of the above examples, remove `echo` to actually perform the delete, `echo` is used as a safety measure and will only display the `del` result to console.

**Edit**

Seeing as you specifically have a list of files (as per one of you comments) to exclude, you can use something like this. You have to create a file called `exclusion.txt` and add the files to exclude in list form:

```
b.txt
c.txt
file with space.txt
d.txt
```

Then create the batch file and add the code below. When ran, it will prompt for the file extention to filter on, where you can type an extension. i.e `txt` or simply press <kbd>enter</kbd> to perform a delete on all files, except the excluded ones. Just to be safe, I added an additional `for` loop to simply echo the files and prompt you if you are sure you want to delete the files.

```
@echo off
set cnt=0 & set excl= & set ext=
echo(
if not exist exclusion.txt echo You have not created an "exclusion.txt" file. & echo( & echo You need to create it first, then rerun the script & echo( & pause & goto :eof
echo Ensure you have listed all files to be excluded in "exclusion.txt"  file
echo(
set /p "ext=Add File extention to search on (txt, pdf, etc), or press enter for all files: "
if not defined ext goto cont
if not "%ext:~0,1%"=="." set "ext=.%ext%"
set "ext=*%ext%"
:cont
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (exclusion.txt) do (
    set /a cnt+=1   
    set "nlr!cnt!=%%a"
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
    if not defined excl (
         set "excl=!nlr%%i!"
    ) else (
         set "excl=!excl! !nlr%%i!"
   )
)
echo(
echo WARNING: You are about to delete the following files!!
echo(
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %ext% ^|findstr /VIE "%excl%"') do (
     if /i not "%%i"=="exclusion.txt" if not "%%i"=="%~0" echo %%i
)
echo(
Choice /c YN /m "Are you sure you want to delete these files?"
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :eof
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %ext% ^|findstr /VIE "%excl%"') do (
    if /i not "%%i"=="exclusion.txt" if not "%%i"=="%~0" del %%i
)
```

Comment: this is what I am looking for. Thank you. This resolves the problem.